Unable to open tex files and uninstall older version of tex
I am getting problem when I start opening any .tex file. It starts occurring after miktex updating itself.
A suggested, I tried reinstalling the app, but it has now installed two versions in the system and still error message is there.

Have you tried simply reinstalling MiKTeX?

Note that this is an issue with the TeXworks editor as bundled with MiKTeX - you could install TeXworks separately or use a separate editor: your .tex files are not 'broken'.

Yes, after reinstalling the MikTex, there are two versions of Miktex now and still same message.

How to reinstall Texworks editor seperatley?

as you already have two miktex installing more is probably not the best strategy. Try to get rid of the older one. And then run on a command line miktex packages update and perhaps miktex --admin packages update

It is unable to uninstall the older version also, Same error message it shows as in the picture.
